# How to find every 11th UITableView Row?

Tags: ios, swift

I need calculation to solve my programmatical problem. I need to detect number at `10,21,32,43,54...XY,ZX.` this form. So, I can find table row at this row index.

For example, `11%11, 22%11, 33%11, 44%11 => 0`. I need like this solution. How can I do? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The numbers you need all have a remainder of 10 when divided by 11. Is `x % 11 == 10` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
if indexPath.row % 11 == 10 {
    print("Found you!")
}
```

Comment: That does not work.  Sweepers answer in comments is correct - the remainder is 10, not 0.

Comment: Oops! I left out the reminder by mistake. Thanks!